# Bootloader jumping to next boot device

Tags: nasm, bootloader, bios, mbr

So far I've managed to write a simple bootloader using NASM which prints 'Hello world' and then hangs. This bootloader is 512K long and it's stored in a pendrive's MBR. The BIOS is configured to first boot the USB external device and then the hard drive with the corresponding operating system.
Like I said before, the bootloader just hangs after printing 'Hello world' because of a never ending loop instruction (jmp $). So, I would like to know if it's possible to continue with the boot sequence (jumping to the next boot device) after the bootloader has finished it's execution. Is there a way to continue with the OS execution (from the HD) after printing 'Hello world' from the pendrive? Which instruction or interruption would accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's solved now. INT 0x19 will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

On BIOSes compliant with the BIOS Boot Specification INT 0x18 should try the next boot device.

INT 0x19 restarts the boot process, possibly a full reboot.